# Error: C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage

Tags: azure, docker

Steps to reproduce the problem

Step 1. Create a .NET Core 2.0 console app for Dockerization
d:\Hello> dotnet new console

### Step 2. Add a new file dockerfile to the folder d:\Hello:

FROM microsoft/dotnet
WORKDIR /app

### copy csproj and restore as distinct layers

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

## copy and build everything else

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

### ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/Hello.dll"]

Step 3: Push the Docker Image to repository.
d:\Hello> docker image push sandeepsoni/demo

Step 4: Created a New VM in Windows Azure (Windows Server 2016 with Container)

Step 5: From the VM executing the following command
c:> docker run sandeepsoni\demo

It's downloading the files and after extracting giving the following error:
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\67d5b7d6c870c7ec84a26def53bb3882da856a2e55f2f94e52d651293f4e3547\UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified.

Can you please help with the error and solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen such error when I tried to run my Docker images built for Windows Server 1709 (newer and smaller images) on Windows Server 2016 host. MS introduced [major breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility) for their base images. You cannot run images built for Windows 1709 on Windows Server 2016 (long-term support channel) unless you use `hyperv` isolation.

Try to switch base image from

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
```

to

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk-nanoserver-sac2016
```